# how to upload large files via fileupload controller in asp.net

Tags: c#

I am using file upload controller for uploading documents.Here when I'm using files of size say 30mb I'm getting an error saying

> "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.".

Its not even going to the upload button click event.

File upload controller working fine for files having smaller size.

I'm uinsg VS2005 and C#.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use httpruntime module for that, Use `MaxRequestLength` Property, in the configuration section of  web.config file.

[MaxRequestLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx) you may use code like this,

```
 <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="31457280" executionTimeout="36000" />
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add this to your web config

    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="31457280" />
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```